# Debugger constantly throws an exception?

Tags: c#, mono, windows-xp, debugging, monodevelop

I am trying to move our projects over to use MonoDevelop, as we have been having a very bad experience with Visual Studio. Anyways, when ever we go to debug an application, we get a TargetInvocationException and asked to Ignore, Retry, Abort.  Clicking anything other than abort just re-throws the exception and on clicking abort forces MonoDevelop to crash.

[Exception http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/6809/88106588.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/6809/88106588.png)

This happens no matter what project I debug. I even setup a bare minimal Console application and this exception gets thrown every-time. MonoDevelop is setup to use the Microsoft.Net run-time with the Microsoft.Net Debugger set as priority number one. I have tried different settings and all seem to result to the same scenario.

Not sure if this has ever been an issue, but me and another developer I am working with are experiencing the same thing. Also searched through nearly every web page I could find on Google and Yahoo but found nothing.

If anybody knows anything that would be great or can anyone point in the right direction?

EDIT:

Seems if you click Ignore several times, the debugger will fall through and begin debugging the application... that could get very annoying after a while.

Comment: What problems have you been having with Visual Studio?

Comment: Doesn't really matter here as it will not help me...

Comment: You can press Ctrl+C to copy the text of the dialog.

Comment: @SLaks: Didn't realize that :/ ...

Comment: Hoping @mhutch sees this. He is the resident MD guru... ;)

Comment: You should really ask about bugs on project mailinlist or MD bugzilla. https://bugzilla.novell.com/ and http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/monodevelop-list

Comment: We don't know that this is a bug so much as something we just missed in a configuration or preference. Nothing is listed on bugzilla regarding this exception, and no response from lists.ximian...

Answer (score 0):

While its the standard answer we hate to hear - in this case I would recommend trying to reinstall (at least "repair") Visual Studio.  It does look like something got corrupted on your machine.

Comment: Visual Studio is not the target of my issue. The main reason we switched from Visual Studio to MonoDevelop was because we will soon be moving to Linux for testing. I can still use the MD debugger, just have to hit Ignore on the pop-up that shows when the TargetInvocationException gets thrown. Plus our development team would rather support MD so that it can be improved not drop it due to a possible personal error or a bug. Which brings me back to the question above. ;)